# How to characterize rotation and reflection in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, reflection

How can  I prove this  fact using Linear Algebra:

- A rotation is formed by the composition of two reflections in which the lines of reflection intersect.
- The composition of reflections over two parallel lines is equivalent to a tramslation.

I know that in Linear Algebra a matrix $R$ is a rotation matrix $\iff R^T=R^{-1}$ and $\det R=1$

How to show that $R$ is obtained as a reflection of two reflection?

Any help

Comment: Do you already know how to characterize a Reflexion Matrix ?

Comment: No,I dont, how to characterize it

Comment: They are orthogonal matrix with det = -1...

Comment: @Evargalo;Thats a rotation matrix

Comment: Nope, as you correctly wrote a rotation matrix has a positive determinant.

Comment: @Evargalo;can you please show how you got that characterization,any source

Comment: The first answer here should help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058898/having-problem-with-rotation-and-reflection?rq=1

Comment: You’re clearly not dealing with linear transformations of the plane: how can you have two parallel lines that both go through the origin? As well, there’d be no reason to include in the first part of your exercise the condition that the lines of reflection intersect since _all_ lines through the origin intersect. You’ll have to look beyond products of $2\times2$ matrices to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If we have two lines $y=kx$ and $y=lx$ (lines through the origin) then reflections across those two are respectively represented with matrix

$$R_1=\begin{bmatrix}
       {2-k^2\over k^2+2} &  {4k\over k^2+2} \\
         {2k\over k^2+2}&  {k^2-2\over k^2+2}  \\
       \end{bmatrix}$$
and

$$R_2=\begin{bmatrix}
       {2-l^2\over l^2+2} &  {4l\over l^2+2} \\
         {2l\over l^2+2}&  {l^2-2\over l^2+2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

where $k=\tan \alpha$ and $l=\tan \beta$

[image]

While rotation matrix around origin for angle $\varphi$ is
$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
      \cos \varphi &  -\sin \varphi \\
        \sin \varphi &  \cos \varphi   \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

So you have to calculate the $${2-k^2\over k^2+2} {2-l^2\over l^2+2}+  {4k\over k^2+2}   {2l\over l^2+2}$$ and the result should be $\cos 2(\beta -\alpha)$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the image below:

[image]

Let we want to reflect the green point on the right side of the red line $y=mx$ or $y=x\cdot\tan\theta_1$ to the other green point on the left side of the red line. Let the polar coordinates of the primary point be $(r,\theta)$; then within the reflection the angle of the points increases as much as $2(\theta_1-\theta)$ and the secondary angle of the reflected point would be $\theta+2(\theta_1-\theta)=2\theta_1-\theta$ therefore the point $(r,\theta)$ would be mapped to $(r,2\theta_1-\theta)$. If another reflection happens along $y=x\cdot \tan\theta_2$ the final position of the point becomes $$(r,2\theta_2-(2\theta_1-\theta))=(r,2\theta_2-2\theta_1+\theta)$$which means that two reflections in a row lead to a rotation as much as $2\theta_2-2\theta_1$